# Timezone not recognized after SetTimeZoneInformation on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, timezone

I am trying to change timezone on Windows 10 using Windows API and by following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-settimezoneinformation?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I am passing timezone bias, standard name and daylight name that are for sure in the Registry as accepted timezones ("Central Europe Standard Time" and "Central Europe Daylight Time"). Clock is being set to correct time but when I open timezone settings in Control Panel I see message `Your current time zone is not recognized. Please select a valid time zone.`. When I click on `Change time zone` button I see that my timezone is selected in dropdown menu but it is not being displayed when I enter the settings. How can I change this or check if timezone is correctly set somewhere in Registry or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- Don't use `SetTimeZoneInformation`, as it doesn't support the complete "dynamic" time zone information that is used in modern Windows.  Use [`SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-setdynamictimezoneinformation) instead.  (The docs are slightly misleading in this regard, as this has been the case from Windows Vista and newer, not just Windows 7 and 8.)
- Ignore the sample in the `SetTimeZoneInformation` doc.  It has hardcoded information about the time zone's bias and DST information.  That's not a good idea.  Instead, use the [`EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-enumdynamictimezoneinformation) function to locate the zone with the desired ID in the `TimeZoneKeyName` field.  When found, pass that `DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structure to the `SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation` function to change the time zone.
- The string `"Central Europe Standard Time"` is the ID (key name) for the time zone with the following English localized strings associated with it:

  - Display Name: `"(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague"`
  - Standard Name: `"Central Europe Standard Time"`
  - Daylight Name: `"Central Europe Daylight Time"`
- That the ID and the English Standard Name happen to match is purely coincidental.  Not all Windows time zones match in English, and they certainly *won't* match if the OS language is not English.  Don't assume that they will.
- The string `"Central Europe Daylight Time"` is *not* a time zone ID.  It's just a localized human-readable string for the name of the time zone used when daylight time is in effect.
- As `SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation` requires the `SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME` privilege, you might find it easier to execute the `TZUtil.exe` utility with the `/s` parameter to set the time zone by ID.  It already has that privilege.

Comment: thanks, it worked! I ended up using the combination of `EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation` and the `SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`, where I first find a dynamic tz info based on standard name and pass it to the setter. cheers!

Comment: just a little edit, you were right about localization and that standard and daylight names are translated to your local OS language, however TimeZoneKeyName from `DynamicTimezoneInformation` is used as a key and is always in English so it can be used always. :)

Comment: Yes - that is correct.  The key names are always those exact strings (including any punctuation) and are never localized.  They come from the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`.  They're literally the registry key names.